# Доступ к элементам ListBox в WPF

Tags: wpf

Дорогие хакеры, как получить доступ к элементам listBox, тобишь у меня в нем checkBox и кнопка. Почему я не могу получить методы и свойства классов Button и СheckBox если я запрашиваю их через Items.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

помогите плиз

Comment: Если вы пишете на WPF, вам вовсе не должно такого хотеться. Зачем вам внутренние элементы?

Comment: @VladD В WPF хорошо сделана анимация,более красиво. Смысл программы в том чтобы люди, в данном случае курсанты, были выбраны и отправлены на печать. Мне нужно добраться до свойства IsChecked, а в итемсах это не предусмотрено

Comment: А почему вы не берёте значение из привязки? Я надеюсь, вы не создаёте элементы списка вручную?

Answer (score 0):

ListBox.Items возвращает коллекцию элементов типа object.
Для доступа к свойствам определенных объектов Вам необходимо привести элемент коллекции к нужному типу.

```
object item = listBox.Items[i];
if(item is CheckBox)
   CheckBox cbx = item as CheckBox;
```

Comment: Чет этот код отказывается работать...

Answer (score 0):

```
 private List<CheckBox> checkingList()
    {
        List<CheckBox> checkingList = new List<CheckBox>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listBoxKursants.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (listBoxKursants.Items[i] is CheckBox)
            {
                CheckBox c = (CheckBox)listBoxKursants.Items[i];
                checkingList.Add(c);
            }
        }
        return checkingList;
    }
```

Решил. Таким способом мы получаем доступ к CheckBox как к масиву и получаем доступ к каждому чеку в листе